# Need help on Breakout game collision bug

Tags: java, swing

This is a grade 12 OPP assignment.

Currently I have a problem that the ball occasionally would go into the blocks instead of reflecting.

Here's my code:

how the main checks if the ball is hitting a block:

```
public void theBall(){
    //System.out.println(blocks.size());
    if(!started){
        balls.get(0).withPaddle(paddle.returnX());
    }
    if(started){
        for(int i=0;i<balls.size();i++){
            if(balls.get(i).returnX()>=0 && balls.get(i).returnX()<=800 && balls.get(i).returnY()>=0){
                balls.get(i).move();
            }
            if(balls.get(i).returnX()+balls.get(i).returnDx()<= 0){
                balls.get(i).collide(1);//collide with left wall
            }
            if(balls.get(i).returnX()+10+balls.get(i).returnDx() >= 800){
                balls.get(i).collide(2);//collide with right wall
            }
            if(balls.get(i).returnY()-balls.get(i).returnDy() <= 0){
                balls.get(i).collide(3);//collide with up wall
            }

            if(paddle.returnX() < balls.get(i).returnX() && balls.get(i).returnX()< paddle.returnX()+paddle.returnSize() && balls.get(i).returnY()-balls.get(i).returnDy() >= 545){//fix this && balls.get(i).returnY()-balls.get(i).returnDy() <= 560
                balls.get(i).collidePaddle(balls.get(i).returnX()-paddle.returnX());//collide with paddle
                //System.out.println(ball.returnDy());
            }
            for(int j=0;j<blocks.size();j++){
                //blocks.get(j).getHit(balls.get(i));
                if(balls.get(i).returnX()+10+balls.get(i).returnDx() >= blocks.get(j).returnX() && balls.get(i).returnX()+10+balls.get(i).returnDx() <= blocks.get(j).returnX()+5 && balls.get(i).returnY() >= blocks.get(j).returnY() && balls.get(i).returnY() < blocks.get(j).returnY()+50){
                    if(!blocks.get(j).returnHit()){
                        balls.get(i).collide(2);//collide with right wall (block's left)
                        blocks.get(j).getHit(balls.get(i));
                        System.out.println("boiboiboiboibo1");
                    }
                }

                if(balls.get(i).returnX()+balls.get(i).returnDx() <= blocks.get(j).returnX()+50 && balls.get(i).returnX()+balls.get(i).returnDx() >= blocks.get(j).returnX()+45 && balls.get(i).returnY() >= blocks.get(j).returnY() && balls.get(i).returnY() < blocks.get(j).returnY()+50){
                    if(!blocks.get(j).returnHit()){
                        balls.get(i).collide(1);//collide with left wall (block's right)
                        blocks.get(j).getHit(balls.get(i));
                        System.out.println("boiboiboiboibo2");
                    }
                }

                if(balls.get(i).returnX() >= blocks.get(j).returnX() && balls.get(i).returnX() < blocks.get(j).returnX()+50 && balls.get(i).returnY()-balls.get(i).returnDy() <= blocks.get(j).returnY()+50 && balls.get(i).returnY()-balls.get(i).returnDy() >= blocks.get(j).returnY()+45){
                    if(!blocks.get(j).returnHit()){
                        balls.get(i).collide(3);//collide with up wall (block's bottom)
                        blocks.get(j).getHit(balls.get(i));
                        System.out.println("boiboiboiboibo3");
                    }
                }
                if(balls.get(i).returnX() >= blocks.get(j).returnX() && balls.get(i).returnX() < blocks.get(j).returnX()+50 && balls.get(i).returnY()+10-balls.get(i).returnDy() >= blocks.get(j).returnY() && balls.get(i).returnY()+10-balls.get(i).returnDy() <= blocks.get(j).returnY()+5){
                    if(!blocks.get(j).returnHit()){
                        balls.get(i).collide(4);//collide with down wall (block's top)
                        blocks.get(j).getHit(balls.get(i));
                        System.out.println("boiboiboiboibo4");
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int j=0;j<specialBlocks.size();j++){
                if(balls.get(i).returnX()>=specialBlocks.get(j).returnX() && balls.get(i).returnX()<=specialBlocks.get(j).returnX()+100 && balls.get(i).returnY()>=specialBlocks.get(j).returnY() && balls.get(i).returnY()<=specialBlocks.get(j).returnY()+100){
                    oneAndThreeBalls(i, j);
                    balls.get(i).changeType(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How the ball reflects:

```
public void collide(int collideWith){
    if(collideWith==1){//collide with left wall
        if(90<direction && direction<180){
            direction = 180-direction;
        }
        if(180<direction && direction<270){
            direction = 540-direction;
        }
    }
    if(collideWith==2){//collide with right wall
        if(0<direction && direction<90){
            direction = 180-direction;
        }
        if(270<direction && direction<360){
            direction = 540-direction;
        }
    }
    if(collideWith==3){//collide with up wall
        direction = 360-direction;
    }
    if(collideWith==4){//collide with down wall
        direction = 360-direction;

    }
}
```

It is very clear to me that the bug is because of the double checking of the boundaries. When the ball is at the corner of a block, it happens. But that's the only way I can think of to check for the ball's position to reflect. Any ideas of how I can fix this bug? Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `continue;` in the for loop once you have found one collision. This will prevent the program from running multiple collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it so:

1) After doing a bounce, you stop checking collision for that ball until the next tick of the game. That way a ball can only bounce once per tick.

2) After colliding with and bouncing off of a block, you ignore collision between that specific block and the ball until such time as the ball does not overlap the block. That way a ball can't spuriously bounce off of a block twice on the same impact.

Btw, you have a lot of copied and pasted code with only slight changes in numbers and so on. If you found a way to restate it in terms of a method you keep calling with slightly different parameters, your code will become a lot neater and the underlying symmetry of the problem will also be more obvious.

Comment: Thank you, but even the first hit could be the wrong direction of collision though.

Comment: @cook cook Only if the ball is moving so fast that it can embed itself half way through a block in one tick. If it cannot, then if you hit a block's corner, it doesn't matter which way you bounce off - both are equally valid as they'll move you away from the block. For an inner corner, you'll bounce off one than the other, so even if you are embedded in it for one tick it doesn't matter.

Comment: I still don't think it's because of double bouncing. I think it's because of the ball has two ways to go and one would be the wrong way. For example, if the ball is going to the bottom right corner with a degree of 45. If the collide happens to be with the bottom wall, it would be normal which reflects at an angle of 315. But if the collide happens to be with the right wall. Then the ball would reflect with an angle of 135, which would go into the block.

Comment: my 0 degree is parallel to the x-axis by the way.

Comment: @cook cook No matter which order the collisions happen in the final angle seems to be OK in your example, so perhaps your problem is just that you don't allow collisions to happen deep inside of an obstruction (so if it bounces and on the next tick is far inside of it it doesn't get bounced again and allowed to leave)